# Adding values based off flag

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a variable called `flagZero` and I want to add a zero for each value in `flagZero`, how can I do that in Python?

For example :

```
flagZero = 3
String = '42'
```

value wanted :

```
00042
```

I could probably do this in a loop but was wondering if there was another function in Python to do it easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
flagZero = 3
string = '42'

new_string = flagZero * '0' + string
new_string
```

Output:

```
00042
```

Comment: This was my solution, I guess I'll have to upvote you instead

Answer (score 3):

There is a `zfill` method:

```
print(String.zfill(flagZero + len(String)))
```

Output:

```
00042
```

Comment: i did look at that function, makes sense